# Lync 2013 API with SharePoint Provider Hosted app

Tags: office-365

How can i use Lync 2013 API with SharePoint Provider Hosted app ?

Comment: You have to be way more specific describing what you want to do.

Comment: i want to start a Lync 2013 meet-now meeting,
so can i use Lync 2013 SDK in my SharePoint Provider Hosted app ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to develop for Lync Online or Lync On-premise. Lync SDK is available for both enviroments. Just reference the dlls in provider hosted apps, satisfy the requirements of respective SDKs and you're good to go.

Here is some information regarding the APIs:

Working [with Meeting APIs for On-premise Lync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933089%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk_example1)

[Lync online administration and management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync-online-administration-and-management.aspx). P.S. Lync Online does not support server-based custom development. Lync client APIs are the only supported development APIs for Lync Online.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any API in Prodiver hosted apps, you just need to make sure your "back-end"-app supports the API, that is not up to SharePoint in the provider hosted model.

For example, your Provider Hosted part of the App can be Web Forms, MVC, php, or whatever really